# String split function in C

Tags: c, string, split, linked-list, c-strings

I'm trying to write a string splitting function in C, much resembling ones already available in other higher-level languages.

In order to save myself the hassle of constant memory (re-)allocation with standard C arrays, I thought I could try to do it using a linked list. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sList {
    char* str;
    struct sList* next;
};

int splitstr (const char* str, const char del, struct sList* subs) {
    int subs_nb = 1, i = 0, len = 0;
    char* s = str;
    struct sList* sub = subs;

    while (i < strlen(s)) {
        if (s[i] == del) {
            sub = malloc(sizeof(struct sList));
            sub->str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

            strncpy(sub->str, s, len);
            sub->str[len] = '\0';

            s = s+i;

            i = 0;
            len = 0;
            subs_nb++;
            sub = sub->next;
        } else {
            len++;
        }

        i++;
    }
    sub = malloc(sizeof(struct sList));
    sub->str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s)+1));
    strcpy(sub->str, s);
    sub->next = NULL;

    return subs_nb;
}
```

I also wrote alongside it a getter function - that I tested separately - to easily access whatever member of the linked list by index:

```
struct sList* sList_get(struct sList* list, int a) {
    struct sList* l = list;
    
    int i = 0;
    while(l != NULL) {
        if (i == a) return list;

        l = l->next;
        i++;
    }

    // If the program reaches this line, a is greater than the number of existing elements in the list
    return NULL;
}
```

Finally, I tried to write a simple unit test to see whether this works as intended:

```
int main () {
    struct sList* list;

    splitstr("bla.bla.bla.bla.bla.", '.', list);

    printf("%s\n", sList_get(list, 0)->str);

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output being the substring preceding the first occurence of `.`: `bla`.

As is usual when messing with dynamic memory though, I get a segmentation fault.

Compiling with `-g` and running the program through gdb, I noticed that, up to the first `sub = malloc(...)`, both `sub` and `subs` are pointing to the same address. However, as soon as it gets to the next instruction, `sub->str = malloc(...)`, `sub` suddenly points to a different address:

```
(gdb)
35              sub = malloc(sizeof(struct sList));
(gdb) print subs
$1 = (struct sList *) 0x555555555100 <_start>
(gdb) print sub
$2 = (struct sList *) 0x555555555100 <_start>
(gdb) n
36              sub->str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
(gdb) print subs
$3 = (struct sList *) 0x555555555100 <_start>
(gdb) print sub
$4 = (struct sList *) 0x5555555592a0
```

Thinking it's most likely a memory leak, I thought then to run it through valgrind, which reported a `definitely lost` at every `sub = malloc(...)` instruction.

What's the problem here?

Comment: [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)

Comment: `sub = sub->next;` is wrong. You never set `sub->next`. And you're losing the pointer to the element you just allocated.

Comment: How is this function supposed to use the input `subs` list? Are the new items added to the end of that list?

Comment: First you set `sub = subs`, but then you immediately overwrite it with `sub = malloc(...)`. In order to add to a list, you need to create the new node in a different variable, e.g. `new_node`. Then you can do `sub->next = new_node;`. Make sure you set `new_node.next = NULL;`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo If I was just looking for something that works, I would have used that. But I'm more interested in understanding how things work, and I think trying to "re-invent the wheel" is a lot more fit for that purpose.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I fixed it. It works perfectly as intended now. How can I flag the question as having been resolved?

Comment: You flag it by accepting the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

As @Barmar pointed out, I got the memory allocation order wrong; if I try to `sub = malloc(...)` after having set it to `subs`, instead of allocating memory for `subs`, it makes it so `sub` now points to a completely different address in memory returned by `malloc`, irrespective of what `subs` points to.

I rewrote the code as following, and it now works perfectly as intended:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sList {

    char* str;
    struct sList* next;

};

int splitstr (const char* str, const char del, struct sList* subs);

struct sList* sList_get(struct sList* list, int a);

int main () {
    struct sList* list = malloc(sizeof(struct sList));

    splitstr("bla.bla.hahaha.bla.bLa", '.', list);

    printf("%s\n", sList_get(list, 2)->str);

    return 0;
}


int splitstr (const char* str, const char del, struct sList* subs) {
    if (subs == NULL) return -1;

    int subs_nb = 1, i = 0, len = 0;
    char* s = str;

    struct sList* sub = subs;

    while (i < strlen(s)) {
        if (s[i] == del) {
            sub->str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

            strncpy(sub->str, s, len);
            sub->str[len] = '\0';

            s = s+i+1;

            i = 0;
            len = 1;
            subs_nb++;
            sub->next = malloc(sizeof(struct sList));
            sub = sub->next;
        } else {
            len++;
        }

        i++;
    }
    sub->str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s)+1));
    strcpy(sub->str, s);
    sub->next = NULL;

    return subs_nb;
}


struct sList* sList_get(struct sList* list, int a) {
    struct sList* l = list;
    
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        if (l == NULL) return NULL;

        l = l->next;
    }

    return l;
}
```

(I also rewrote the getter function as I thought it was misbehaving for a second - I'm not sure whether it actually was.)

Comment: `char* s = str;` - is refused by my compiler when I put it in "pedantic" mode. `str` is a `const char*`.